# I have to click twice to re-render my updated state and the callback function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read several stack overflow answers about this and tried implementing them with no success. I see that this is a common problem that has a few answers, callback functions, componenentDidUPdate and if you're desperate enough setTimeout. None of these work for me, not even setTimeout. I figure I must be doing something else wrong.

My current setStates have callback functions on them, but are not returning the updated state, they're returning the old state.

How can I fix this so my view renders with the updated state? this.state.scheduled needs to be mapped with the updated state immediately after the buttons are clicked.

```
state = {
    chosenDate: 'initial',
    scheduled: this.props.scheduled,
  }; 

chooseDate = (dateChosen) => {
    this.setState({ chosenDate: dateChosen })

    const today       = new Date();
    const yesterday = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-1);

    if(this.state.chosenDate === 'today') {
      this.setState({ scheduled: this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled));
    }

    if(this.state.chosenDate === 'yesterday') {
      this.setState({ scheduled: this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(yesterday), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled));;
    }
  };

render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    let eventDate = '';

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div>
        {this.state.scheduled.map( event => {
          //https://date-fns.org/docs/format
          const scheduledDate = dateFnsFormat(new Date(event.scheduled_at), 'EEEE, MMMM do');
          const scheduledTime = dateFnsFormat(new Date(event.scheduled_at), 'p');
          //console.log('scheduledDate', scheduledDate);
          var dateHeader = <h3>{scheduledDate}</h3>;
          if (scheduledDate === eventDate) {
            dateHeader = "";
          } else {
            eventDate = scheduledDate;
          }
          return (
          <div key={event.post_id}>
          {dateHeader}
            <div onClick={() => this.editPost(event.post_id)} className={classes.event} key={event.post_id}>
            <p className={classes.eventTime}>{scheduledTime}</p>
            <p className={classes.eventTitle} title={event.description}>{event.title}</p>
            <div className={classes.socialIcons}>
              {event.platforms && event.platforms.includes("f") &&
                <img src={facebookcolor} alt="facebook" />
              }
              {event.platforms && event.platforms.includes("t") &&
                <img src={twittercolor} alt="twitter" />
              }
              {event.platforms && event.platforms.includes("i") &&
                <img src={instagramcolor} alt="instagram" />
              }
              {event.platforms && event.platforms.includes("p") &&
                <img src={pinterestcolor} alt="pinterest" />
              }
              {event.platforms && event.platforms.includes("y") &&
                <img src={youtubecolor} alt="youtube" />
              }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>)
        })}
        </div>

        <div className={classes.chooseDate}>
          <p>Choose a date</p>
          <button onClick={() => this.chooseDate('today')}>Today</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.chooseDate('next week')}>Next 7 days</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.chooseDate('next month')}>Next 30 days</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.chooseDate('yesterday')}>yesterday</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.chooseDate('last week')}>Last 7 days</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.chooseDate('last month')}>Last 30 days</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: First you `this.setState({ chosenDate: dateChosen })` then immediately try to use `this.state.chosenDate` in a conditional below. This won't work since `setState` is async. There's zero guarantee that `this.state.chosenDate` is what you set it as above.

Comment: That was the problem, I just created a new function to put the conditional statements into and it's working now! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lux for helping me solve this!

I needed to create a new function to hold the conditional statements, and call them from the setState in the chooseDate function.

```
chooseDate = (dateChosen) => {
    this.setState({ chosenDate: dateChosen }, () => this.updateList())
  };

  updateList = () => {
    const today       = new Date();
    const yesterday = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-1);
    const inAWeek   = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+7);
    const in30Days   = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+30);
    const lastWeek   = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+7);
    const Last30Days   = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()+30);

    if(this.state.chosenDate === 'today') {
      this.setState({ scheduled: this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled));
    }

    if(this.state.chosenDate === 'yesterday') {
      this.setState({ scheduled: this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(yesterday), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled));;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const today       = new Date();
const yesterday = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-1);
this.setState({ chosenDate: dateChosen }, () => {
  if(this.state.chosenDate === 'today') {
    this.setState({ scheduled: this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled));
  }

  if(this.state.chosenDate === 'yesterday') {
    this.setState({ scheduled: this.props.scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(yesterday), 'yyyy-MM-dd')) }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled));;
  }

})
```

what i did was wrap the other functions after the setState of the first because since the setState is async, you will not get the new value until you press again, but by using the callback function you only use it's value after you make sure that it was updated, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You almost done with this, but the problem is you're trying to use a value before it is updated, because of this.setState is async, the way you code is, it would work at the first time, but actually work for the second time, because the state is updated, so you probably resolve this issue by calculating the next state into the function instead a raw state, so you could do this

```
chooseDate = (dateChosen) => {
  this.setState((previousState) => {
    const { scheduled } = previousState;
    const nextState = { chosenDate: dateChosen }; // prepare the next state
    const today       = new Date();
    const yesterday = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-1);

    if (dateChosen === 'today') {
      nextState.scheduled = scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    }

    if (dateChosen === 'yesterday') {
      nextState.scheduled = scheduled.filter(event => event.scheduled_at.substring(0, 10) === dateFnsFormat(new Date(yesterday), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    }

    return nextState;
  }, () => console.log(this.state.scheduled))
};
```

Doing this you can calculate the next state based on the previous one.

By doing this, you ensure that you component gets updated just one time, so you are saving the second update, so you component get a better performance

Hope it can be useful for you.